# Asymptotically $\binom{2n}{n}\approx\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ or $\binom{2n}{n}\approx2^{2n}$?

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) about the binomial coefficient has the following (asymptotic) estimation for $n$ and $k$ that grow in the same rate (under "Bounds and asymptotic formulas")

$$\log\binom{n}{k}\approx nH_{2}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$$

where $H_{2}\left(\alpha\right)=-\alpha\log\left(\alpha\right)-\left(1-\alpha\right)\log\left(1-\alpha\right)$ is the binary entropy function

Which would imply
$$\binom{2n}{n}\approx2^{2nH_{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}=2^{2n}$$

However, the same paragraph has the following asymptotic estimation of the central binomial coefficient

$$\binom{2n}{n}\approx\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

Aren't these two contradictory? If not, why not and if so, which one is correct?

Comment: One cannot say that$$\log{(f(n))}\sim g(n)\iff f(n)\sim \exp{(g(n))}$$Consider, for example, $f(n)=n\exp{(n)}$ and $g(n)=n$.

Comment: Better to use Stirling formula $$n!\approx\sqrt{2n\pi}\frac{n^n}{e^n}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the approximation symbol $\approx$ where Wikipedia uses the asymptoticity symbol $\sim$. The former is an informal way of saying that two expressions are approximately equal without specifying in which way or to what extent. By contrast, the latter makes a well-defined statement about the two sides: $f(x)\sim g(x)$ is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition) to mean

$$
\lim\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1\;,
$$

where a particular limit process, typically $x\to\infty$, is specified or assumed from the context.

The two asymptotic statements that you cite, spelled out properly including the limit process, are

$$
\binom{2n}n\sim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}
$$

and

$$
\log\binom n{\lambda n}\sim_{n\to\infty}-n\left(\lambda\log\lambda+(1-\lambda)\log(1-\lambda)\right)
$$

(where the logarithm can be taken for any base).

There is no contradiction because

$$
\log_2\left(\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\right)=2n-\frac12\log_2(\pi n)\sim_{n\to\infty}2n
$$

since

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}n=0\;.
$$

By contrast, omitting the factor $\frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ in the first result without taking logarithms would make it false.